# Accessing ruby's optparse from a class

Tags: ruby, instance-variables, optparse, attr-accessor

I'm fairly new to ruby. I'm trying to use optparse to influence the way my code executes. I would like to get the results from optparse into my class so I can base some conditionals on it.

I spent a good couple of hours googling (optparse, attr_accessor), and implemented the results as best I could, in a sort of trial-and-error way.

Below, I've tried to provide a minimal working example. I apologise if any of the syntax or presentation is off...

```
require 'optparse'

options = {}
OptionParser.new do |opts|
 opts.banner = "Usage: example.rb [options]"

 opts.on("-v", "--verbose", "Adopt verbose policy") do |v|
  options[:verbose] = v
 end
end.parse!
@options = options

class Chatty

 def initialize
  puts "We're gonna be verbose" if @options[:verbose]
 end

end

Chatty.new
```

The problem is that @options is nil inside the class. This results in a NoMethodError.

```
#  ...in `initialize': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

But I don't know how to get around that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@options` is an instance variable.  The `@options` you reference at the top level is not the same `@options` referenced within your `Chatty` initialization method.

If you want the options to be accessible within `Chatty`, you'll need to pass it in (e.g. upon instantiation). For example, instead of:

```
@options = options

class Chatty

 def initialize
  puts "We're gonna be verbose" if @options[:verbose]
 end

end

Chatty.new
```

you could do:

```
class Chatty

  def initialize(options)
    @options = options
    puts "We're gonna be verbose" if @options[:verbose]
  end

end

Chatty.new(options)
```

Comment: Knew it would be straightforward to someone who knows what they're doing. I did once try passing options to the class by writing:
     class Chatty(options)